# easily change/getting image from googledrive and display in website

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

from this article https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en . google doesn't support web hostings. Is there any way that i can get my image from googledrive for example like this:

for example i have a shared folder like this:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByzxsoB7kICPUjVEVG12a0hNSWc

and that shared folder contains with 
myimage1.jpg,
myimage2.jpg,
myimage3.jpg,

i want to select/change it in my website by using that image. 
For example i uploaded another image in my googledrive to replace my web image easily. Please help.

something like this :

```
<img src = "googledriveimage/myimage1.jpg">
```

after i want to replace the image. then i would go to googledrive and replace the myimage1.jpg with another image but the same file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a PHP script to fetch the desired image from google drive and return it back to the HTTP client.

Refer to the flow in the diagram:
[image]

1. User views the HTML page in his/her browser
2. The browser sends a HTTP GET request to your PHP script.
3. The PHP script is hosted either in a publicy accessible web server (or uses a cloud service provider e.g. Google App Engine, you could use any cloud hosting service provider). The script would use the Google Drive SDK to use OAUTH and request the pre-specified image file from Google Drive. Here, you need to use either the SDK or wrap the request in the proper JSON/XML format as specified by Google Drive API. You need to embed the desired logic of translating a front-end visible image filename to the real Google Drive filename.
4. Google drive translates the request, checks authentication and retrieves the image.
5. The image is returned back to the PHP script.
6. The PHP script encodes the image and sets the right MIME type, headers, etc.
7. The user is able to view the image on the page.

To clarify, you dont need to host your PHP script in Google App Engine, you could host it on any other web hosting provider infrastructure.

I've used Google drive APIs in servlets deployed on Google App engine. I haven't used PHP in GAE, but have quoted the PHP references since you indicated familiarity with PHP. If you're interested in using GAE, first read the concepts related to GAE here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/concepts and then the PHP how-tos for using the SDK and deploying the app using PHP - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/how-to . Also refer to this documentation - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/ .

I've included the concept of how you can solve your problem, you need to go through the documents and implement this yourselves.

Comment: i mean how can i write a servlet ?

Comment: any example of providing that scheme sir ?

Comment: ohhh.. i've seen the link you provided. it seems like in java ? .. i am using php . . Is there available in php ?

Comment: i dont really get it :'(

Comment: how can GAE apps help my problem sir ?

Comment: pleasse can you edit your answer sir. clear steps for specific PHP

Comment: Updated to answer queries in your comments.

Comment: what is PHP APP do you mean ?? .. how can i make it ?. i searched all about PHP app. sounds like nothing..

Comment: sir do you know what are you talking about in service provider such as google app engine ?.. google app engine is something nothing to do with getting dynamic images.. By the way. did you already tried your answer ?

Comment: I've included the concept of how you can solve your problem, you need to go through the documents and implement this yourselves.